# Unable to use `string.replace(regex:RegExp, map: (match, ...args:any[]) => string): string` in TypeScript

Tags: regex, typescript

The compiler complaints in the following example:

```
    function test() {
        var regex = /.+/ig;
        ''.replace(regex, function (matched, p1) { return ''; });
    }
```

Is it a bug in TypeScript?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So here's the declaration line from lib.d.ts that you're trying to match:

```
replace(searchValue: RegExp, replaceValue: (substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string): string;
```

At compile time we don't know how many matches the replaceValue function might have to handle.  There might be 0 matches so your function needs to say it can handle that.  Here it is rewritten:

```
''.replace(regex, function (matched: string, p1?: string) { return ''; });
```

With `p1` typed as optional the compiler is satisfied we can handle that case.  There's no way to specify that a parameter can be optional without also specifying the type so I've done that as well.

Comment: Note you can also add '...' to p1 like this: 

var r = /asdf/g
''.replace(r, function(matched, ...p1) {
 return '';
});

Comment: The error message is for parameter 1, not parameter 2. String.prototype.replace seems to only accept string for parameter 1 in this case.